# Select entire column in table using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table in an excel sheet and I want to select the entire first row. Is there an easier/faster way to reference a table than the normal

```
 Range("A2").End(xlDown).Select
```

method? Seems that by using a Table I should gain an easier access route to the data.
Thanks.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

With these codes you can select different parts of a table.

Entire Table:
`ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.Select`

Table Header Row:
`ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").HeaderRowRange.Select`

Table Data:
`ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").DataBodyRange.Select`

Third Column:
`ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").ListColumns(3).Range.Select`

Third Column (Data Only):
`ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").ListColumns(3).DataBodyRange.Select`

Select Row 4 of Table Data:
`ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").ListRows(4).Range.Select`

Select 3rd Heading:
`ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").HeaderRowRange(3).Select`

Select Data point in Row 3, Column 2:
`ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").DataBodyRange(3, 2).Select`

Subtotals:
`ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").TotalsRowRange.Select`

For a full guide on tables see [The VBA Guide To ListObject Excel Tables](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/6/20/the-vba-guide-to-listobject-excel-tables).

Comment: My table header starts from `A3`. So. I did this `ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table3").HeaderRowRange.DataBodyRange.Copy` . This gives error. How can select table starts from `A3`?

Comment: What do you exactly want to copy? The whole table or just the header? Both for both an example is given in this answer.

Comment: I need the table with header. However, My table header starts from `A3`. So, when I copy table into a different sheet using `("Table 1").Range().copy` it takes `A1`, `A2` too, which I don't need. I tried `("Table1").HeaderRowRange.DataBodyRange.Copy` it does not work. What is the solution for that?

Comment: @user9431057 no `ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.Select` will only select eveything that belongs to the table nothing more. I recommend to ask a new question to that and show a screenshot in that question. This cannot be answered in a comment.

Comment: yeah, that is a little tricky, I will post the question as soon as I can!

Comment: fyi from [here](https://www.dingbatdata.com/2017/11/24/referencing-listobjects-with-vba/): exclude sheet specification and get column by name: `Range("Table1").ListObject.ListColumns("ColumnName")`

Comment: How do you select columns 3 to 5?

Comment: To select the data only of a column in your existing active cell, I use this: ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").ListColumns(ActiveCell.Column).DataBodyRange.Select

Answer (score 0):

This is the shortest way I know:

```
Rows(1).Select
```

[Here](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/entire-rows-columns.html) you can fin some example about it.

Comment: this doesn't select a row of a table but a row of the entire sheet. But we are talking about formatted tables in a sheet here. See [Overview of Excel tables](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Overview-of-Excel-tables-7ab0bb7d-3a9e-4b56-a3c9-6c94334e492c)