# Find specific records in a table

Tags: vba, excel

I am looking to find only certain records and handle them accordingly. I have a table called `Locations` and one of the columns is labelled `Location`. Currently my code handles ALL locations when I run the macro; however, I would like to write a variation of the macro that runs only certain locations (a range). The location values are all 2 letters followed by 5 numbers.
Example: CA10020

What I want to do is prompt for the starting and ending location values and then process only those ones.
Example: CA10001 to CA13240
Everything before and after those values would be ignored... but those values AND everything between them would be handled.

Normally I have a good idea where to start and through trial and error I can figure out the rest. In this case I am stumped on where to begin. As you can tell, I am not a VBA expert.

I currently have this code which handles ALL the records which is not what I need to do now:

```
For i = 1 To Range("Locations").Rows.Count
    Range("F3").Value = Range("Locations[Location]")(i)
    'I have other code here that handles the new value of cell F3
Next i
```

UPDATE:
I added this code:

```
Dim Start_Location As Variant
Dim End_Location As Variant
Start_Location = InputBox("What is the starting location?")
End_Location = InputBox("What is the ending location?")
```

...but I have no idea how to handle those values now.

Comment: How will you be passing in your Start and End locations. I.E., how will you tell the macro to look at `CA10001 to CA13240`? Input Box with text? Input Box with Range Selector? Data validation? Will the values be in some static cell?

Comment: Have a look here for how to select different parts of a table: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43541445/select-entire-column-in-table-using-excel-vba/43541508#43541508

Comment: Self promotion eh @Pᴇʜ ;). Only joking. Good solution, I up ticked

Comment: @Pᴇʜ - That shows me how to select certain parts of the table but not how to filter certain values.

Comment: See the update to the original post

Comment: You can use the [WorksheetFunction.Match Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.WorksheetFunction.Match) to find the row number of user input `Start_Location` and `End_Location` and then run your `For` loop from/to these row numbers.

Comment: I was having trouble Google'n what to do prior to posting but kept searching and was able to come up with the answer I just posted. Not sure if it is the cleanest or most efficient way to do it but it works

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim Start_Location As Variant
Dim End_Location As Variant
Start_Location = InputBox("What is the starting location?")
End_Location = InputBox("What is the ending location?")

For i = 1 To Range("Locations").Rows.Count
    If Range("Locations[Location]")(i) >= Start_Location And Range("Locations[Location]")(i) <= End_Location Then

        Range("F3").Value = Range("Locations[Location]")(i)

        'Code to handle the new value of cell F3
    End If

Next i
```

Comment: The issue here is that the `For` loop still runs through *all* rows in the range. You can reduce the runtime by running through rows between start and end location only. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to find the first and last location using `Match()` to reduce the runtime of the loop.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ProcessLocationFromTo()
    Dim FirstLocation As Variant
    Dim LastLocation As Variant
    FirstLocation = InputBox("What is the starting location?")
    LastLocation = InputBox("What is the ending location?")

    Dim RngLocation As Range
    Set RngLocation = Range("Locations[Location]")

    Dim FirstRow As Long
    On Error GoTo ERR_FIND_LOCATION
    FirstRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(FirstLocation, RngLocation, 1)
    On Error GoTo 0

    Dim LastRow As Long
    On Error GoTo ERR_FIND_LOCATION
    LastRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(LastLocation, RngLocation, 1)
    On Error GoTo 0

    Dim i As Long
    For i = FirstRow To LastRow
        Range("F3").Value = RngLocation(i)

        'Code to handle the new value of cell F3
    Next i


    Exit Sub

ERR_FIND_LOCATION:
    MsgBox "The location was out of range." & vbCrLf & "It must be between """ & RngLocation(1) & """ and """ & RngLocation(RngLocation.Count) & """."
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

**Note** that this only works if the table is sorted by location! Otherwise you will need to sort by location before running the procedure:

```
With ListObjects("Locations").Sort
    .SortFields.Clear
    .SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("Locations[[#All],[Location]]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```